# How do I make this figure show up in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to visualize this plot (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-figure-figure-show-in-python/). There is no error, but also no plot. What am I doing wrong?

Additional information: I suspect it has something to do with my Jupyter notebook settings, but I cannot find the right setting. I have tried several solutions including the tutorial here (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_plotting.htm)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x**2)+np.cos(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label ='Line 1')
ax.plot(x, y - 0.6, label ='Line 2')
ax.legend()
fig.suptitle("""matplotlib.figure.Figure.show()
function Example\n\n""", fontweight ="bold")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Code is fine. It should show up. In fact, you don't need the `fig.show()` line anymore in modern Jupyter. Just put a semi-colon at end of last line, in this case after `...fontweight ="bold")`, so that the plot's Python object code isn't shown. As to why it isn't working on your machine... had it worked before or this is all new stuff? Did you use the Anaconda distribution to install. I would suggest trying that if you haven't.

Comment: If you are just trying to learn and want a place where things like this will work, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and click `laucnh binder`. You'll get a temporary session where that code will work. The session will time out after 10 minutes of inactivity and so if you make a useful notebook or code, download it back to your local machine ASAP so you have it and can use it in a new session. In JupyterLab, which comes up by default, you can drag-and-drop from your local machine into the file browser panel on the left side to add it to the remote temporary session.